# How to use Java StreamAPI in this situtation (using polymorphism)

Tags: java, java-stream, polymorphism

```
@Override
    public ResultBase handle(Request request) {
        for (Movie movie : this.movieArrayList) {
            if (movie.getTitle().equals(request.getTitle())) {
                return new OkResult(movie);
            }
        }
        return new NotFoundResult();
    }
```

I want to apply the STREAM API to the above code

OkResult and NotFoundResult both inherit from the abstract class ResultBase.

The code will return an OkResult if the movie is found in the movie list, and a NotFoundResult otherwise.

```
public final class OkResult extends ResultBase {
    private final Movie movie;

    public OkResult(final Movie movie) {
        super(ResultCode.OK);

        this.movie = movie;
    }

    public Movie getMovie() {
        return this.movie;
    }
}
```

```
public final class NotFoundResult extends ResultBase {
    public NotFoundResult() {
        super(ResultCode.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public ResultBase handle(Request request) {
    return this.movieArrayList.stream()
            .filter(movie -> movie.getTitle().equals(request.getTitle()))
            .map(movie -> new OkResult(movie))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(new NotFoundResult());
}
```

My first attempt looks like this But this has a syntax error A compilation error occurred because Optional<OkResult> is required in orElse(new NotFoundResult()).

So I tried fixing the code using polymorphism. The fixed code looks like this

```
@Override
    public ResultBase handle(Request request) {
        Optional<ResultBase> res = this.movieArrayList.stream()
                .filter(movie -> movie.getTitle().equals(request.getTitle()))
                .map(movie -> (ResultBase) new OkResult(movie))
                .findFirst();

        return res.orElse(new NotFoundResult());
    }
```

Is there a better way? Thanks for reading this long post

Comment: Use `Optional` for starters.

Comment: Minor remark: instead of `orElse(new NotFoundResult());` (which will always create a new `NotFoundResult`, no matter whether `res` is empty or not, we should use `orElseGet(NotFoundResult::new);`, which will only create a `NotFoundResult` if `res` is empty.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the nice comment. Thanks to your comment, I realized the difference between the orElse and orElseGet methods.

Comment: @OleksandrPyrohov I thought the cast was ugly too, thanks for the nice comment. I'm just practicing to use the StramAPI in a variety of ways, and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first attempt looks like this But this has a syntax error A compilation error occurred because Optional is required in orElse(new NotFoundResult()).

How about using the `map` method of `Optional`?

```
public ResultBase handle(Request request) {
         return this.movieArrayList.stream()
             .filter(movie -> movie.getTitle().equals(request.getTitle()))
             .findFirst().map(movie -> (ResultBase) new OkResult(movie))
             .orElseGet(NotFoundResult::new);
}
```

Comment: You can help the compiler with the type inference, using `.<ResultBase>map(movie -> new OkResult(movie))`, then you don’t need a cast. Has no effect on the result nor performance, as the cast is a compile-time thing only. But without the cast, you can also use `.<ResultBase>map( OkResult::new)`…

Comment: @Holger
Thank you! Turing85 came up with a similar solution

Comment: @Gyo no, I did not come up with the solution; I only extended WJS' answer. As such, I think it'd be only fair fi WJS' answer gets the checkmark.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for that but I'm not that concerned about it.  No need for OP to change their acceptance.

Comment: I finally checkmark the WJS's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552534/wjs)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76749604/4216641), which moves the `map`ping after the `findFirst()`, effectively reducing the amount of calculation that must be done (since we map only once), we can eliminate the in-line cast by adding a separate `map` step to cast. We can also use a method reference to call the `OkResult`-constructor. All taken together would look like this:

```
public ResultBase handle(Request request) {
    return this.movieArrayList.stream()
        .filter(movie -> movie.getTitle().equals(request.getTitle()))
        .findFirst()
        .map(OkResult::new)
        .map(ResultBase.class::cast)
        .orElseGet(NotFoundResult::new);
}
```

Comment: “*we can eliminate the in-line cast by adding a separate map step to cast*” Why should “eliminate the in-line cast” be a goal, especially by adding another `map` step? Even if the cast was not eliminated at compile-time already (since it’s a widening conversion), adding another `map` step would never be more efficient than applying it within the same lambda expression. By the way, since this is just a type inference issue, you can simply use `.<ResultBase>map(OkResult::new)`, then you don’t need a cast at all.

Comment: It is all a matter of choice. For me, performance is not the sole factor when writing code. I personally like to have simple `map`pings, i.e. one step per mapping. Others like to add the inference (which is what I initially suggested in a comment), again others like to not use streams or optionals.